# VMWare PowerCLI Get DiskUsage of powered off vm's

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, vmware, powercli, power-state

I'm creating a script that gets all vm's and shows the DiskSpace. THe Problem is, that if a vm is powered off, it won't show the uesed Space of a disk.

Here are two examples: First one with an VM that is powered on:

```
PowerCLI C:\> Get-VM sluwv0039

Name                 PowerState Num CPUs MemoryGB
----                 ---------- -------- --------
sluwv0039            PoweredOn  2        4.000

PowerCLI C:\> $VM = Get-VM sluwv0039
PowerCLI C:\> $VM.guest.disks

CapacityGB      FreeSpaceGB     Path
----------      -----------     ----
49.997          5.417           C:\
```

Example two where the VM is powered off:

```
PowerCLI C:\> Get-VM sluwv0012

Name                 PowerState Num CPUs MemoryGB
----                 ---------- -------- --------
sluwv0012            PoweredOff 4        8.000


PowerCLI C:\> $VM = Get-VM sluwv0012
PowerCLI C:\> $VM.guest.disks
PowerCLI C:\>
```

Note: The Last line is the output. There is no "CapacityGB" etc.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, that property is reading from the guest file system to see how much space is left on the partition. In your case, the C:\ drive. If the VM is off, there's no way for PowerCLI to find that property.

Alternatively, you could look at the `$vm.ExtensionData.Summary.Storage` properties and do some rough conversions. Note: the output of those are in byte, so you'll want to convert them to GB. Example: `$tempVM.ExtensionData.Summary.Storage.Committed / 1GB`

It won't be exact, but it will be better than no output at all.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. At least I won't get a blank variable.

Answer (score 0):

here is example of script to show vm specification:

Get-Vm | Select-Object Name,PowerState,VMHost,NumCPU,MemoryGB,ProvisionedSpaceGB,@{N="HostName";E={@($*.guest.HostName)}},@{N="Gateway";E={@($*.ExtensionData.Guest.IpStack.IpRouteConfig.IpRoute.Gateway.IpAddress[0])}},@{N="DNS";E={$*.ExtensionData.Guest.IpStack.DnsConfig.IpAddress}},@{N="IPAddress";E={@($*.guest.IPAddress -like "192.168.*")}},@{N="Nics";E={@($*.guest.Nics)}},@{N="Datastore";E={@($* | Get-DataStore)}},@{N="Disks";E={@($*.guest.Disks)}},Version,@{N="State";E={@($*.guest.State)}},@{N="OS";E={@($_.guest.OSFullName)}}

the sample output is like this:

Name    State   VMHost  NumCpu  MemoryGB    PowerState  ProvisionedSpaceGB  Version IPAddress   HostName    OS  Nics    Disks   VMwareTools Gateway DNS
test    Running 192.168.32.100  2   1   PoweredOn   43.1085147  v8  192.168.122.1   Elenoon Ubuntu Linux (64-bit)   Network adapter 1:VM Network Network adapter 2:local : :    Capacity:17167286272, FreeSpace:14212493312, Path:/ Capacity:15188623360, FreeSpace:15154872320, Path:/media/files Capacity:10724835328, FreeSpace:10672824320, Path:/var/log Capacity:973770752, FreeSpace:690139136, Path:/boot   guestToolsRunning       127.0.0.1

hope to be useful ;)